# Invalidate username if it contains @ symbol

Tags: login, email, sanitization, username

I would like to let the user login either using username or email.

The only way to find the email is by detecting `@ symbol` using `strpos`.

However WordPress allow `@ symbol` in [username too](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/formatting.php#L874).

Can someone help me to invalidate username if it contains @ symbol in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multi-site installation it is `'wpmu_validate_user_signup'`:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_validate_user_signup', 'wpse_77904_mu_no_at_in_username' );

function wpse_77904_mu_no_at_in_username( $user )
{
    if ( FALSE !== strpos( $user['user_name'], '@' ) )
        $user['errors']->add('user_name',  __( 'That username is not allowed.' ) );

    return $user;
}
```

On single-site it is `'validate_username'`:

```
add_filter( 'validate_username', 'wpse_77904_no_at_in_username', 10, 2 );

function wpse_77904_no_at_in_username( $valid, $username )
{
    if ( FALSE !== strpos( $username, '@' ) )
        return FALSE;

    return $valid;
}
```

Caveat: both not tested. :)

Comment: Great.. It works :)